# PyQt beforeInsert() signal

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to use the beforeInsert() signal emitted by the QSqlRelationalTableModel in PyQt. However, even after I make edits to the model, the slot connected to the signal does't run. When exactly is the beforeInsert() signal emitted? Could someone show a working example of the use of beforeInsert(), or beforeUpdate() for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says "This signal is emitted by insertRowIntoTable() before a new row is inserted into the currently active database table". So it sounds like the signal is *only* emitted when insertRowIntoTable() is called, and not for any other type of model edit.